# Android SSL Time Out Error in Kitkat

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat

I am creating a native app for Android.
It suddenly stops working on `KitKat`.

The API is not able to fetch data from the server and shows an SSL Time out. The API and my app are working fine on Lollipop and Marshmallow.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution :

Actually my Server support TLS version 1.1 and 1.2 only and in android version below lollipop these versions access is by default disabled where as in lollipop and above version it is enabled. Thats why build is not working in pre- lollipop devices.